# set label in cypherquery dynamically

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to store some data in a neo4j db with the following (broken down query) which works, not 100% proper but all data are send to my db:

```
var query2Neo = "CREATE (p:Person { samAccountName:'" + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value + "'});
```

As my next step I try to write the label with real data not just person:

```
 var query2Neo = "CREATE (p:'" + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value + "' { samAccountName:'" + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value + "'})";
```

that's not working, but should I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just due to the single quote around the label.

Your code will generate a query like that `CREATE (n:'Person' { ...})` and it's not valid.

You should use the backtick instead (*`*) so it

```
CREATE (n:`Person` { ...})
```

So your code should be :

```
var query2Neo = "CREATE (p:`" + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value + "` { samAccountName:'" + de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value + "'})";
```

Moreover, for your properties values, you should use query parameters instead of generating the cypher query in your code (but this not possible for label). It's possible to send map as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example of using parameters or map in a query for cypher and net? Best regards